# Sum function in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a small function to do the follow:
 `c = (a/3)*(1/((1+x)*2)+1/((1+x)*4)+1/((1+x)*8))+1/((1+x)*8)`

Input variables are `a` and `x`.  As you can see, the number to multiply by is a multiple of 2 (up to 8).

My main difficult is in the recursive sum. I know that SAS has a SUM function, but I am wondering how to use it in this exercise. I thought the parameter could be `(1/((1+x)*n*2)` (where `n` is a number).
Help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand.  Why not just use the assignment statement as it is?  It will create C from the current values of A and X.  How does either recursion or accumulation enter into the problem?

Comment: I did not think of it. Thanks Tom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can code a loop to iterate the pieces to accumulate. Something like:

```
data want;
  a = 2;
  x = 7;
  steps = 4;
  S = 0;
  do index = 1 to steps;
    S = sum (S, 1/(1+x)*index*2);
  end;
  c = a/3 * S;
run;
```

Comment: sorry, Richard, what do you mean with f in your answer?

Comment: It was a typo, fixed to S to represent the accumulated Sum value (versus f, which I would sometimes use to represent a piece or a factor)